# Dynamically display posts by one author AND from one category on the same page?

Tags: wordpress, templates, loops, categories, author

I'm trying to edit my author.php wordpress template so that it shows posts by any one author, but only from one particular category. So far, I've been trying the query_posts function which fetches the category okay, but not the author. Depending on which way I do it, so far the posts either don't display at all or all posts in that category appear regardless of the author.

This is the appropriate code which I've seen quoted by a wordpress.org admin, but it doesn't work for me and I can't find any other examples. Any ideas why that doesn't work? Thanks for your help in advance.

```
//Gets author info to display on page and for use in query
<?php
    $curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));
?>

//Queries by category and author and starts the loop
<?php
    query_posts('category_name=blog&author=$curauth->ID;'); 
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>

    //HTML for each post

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php echo "<p>". $curauth->display_name ."hasn't written any articles yet.</p>"; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

============ ALSO TRIED ============

```
<?php
    new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'blog', 'author' => $curauth->ID ) );
?>
```

This doesn't work either, however it does filter the posts by author, just not by category! What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task can be done using `pre_get_posts` filter. By this way it's also possible to filter for author in addition than for category:

```
// functions.php    
   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpcf_filter_author_posts' );
   function wpcf_filter_author_posts( $query ){
     // We're not on admin panel and this is the main query
     if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
       // We're displaying an author post lists
       // Here you can set also a specific author by id or slug
       if( $query->is_author() ){
         // Here only the category ID or IDs from which retrieve the posts
         $query->set( 'category__in', array ( 2 ) );           
       }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue, which I solved using a check for `if(in_category('blog'))` after the loop started, like this:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
if(in_category('blog')) {
?>

    <!-- Loop HTML -->

<?php } endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('No posts by this author.'); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Of course the $curauth check would come before this.