# Display posts by one author and only from current category (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I need your help to solve my problem.

So, what I can't make:
For instance, I have a category 'NEWS', this category has some subcategories 'POLITICS', 'SPORT', 'LIFE' etc.

In the sidebar displayed a list of author's names and if I click for some author in some category I need to show only posts written by this author and from the current category, subcategory.

How can I create it? I suppose that it's able to create by pre_get_posts but not sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18512467/1071555 
This is almost what I need, but I need to get current category dynamically for certain user. I try to get category ID from function.php but I receive an empty result. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Display all users that even had been written posts in certain category (I created a carousel slider of it's avatars/names). Then I generate the link and add current category at the end.

```
<ul id="carousel">                                                                                                                                                                                                      
<?php
$current_category = single_cat_title("", false);
$author_array = array();

$args = array(
'numberposts' => -1,
'category_name' => $current_category,
'orderby' => 'author',
'order' => 'ASC'
);
$cat_posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($cat_posts as $cat_post) :
if (!in_array($cat_post->post_author,$author_array)) {
$author_array[] = $cat_post->post_author;
}
endforeach;
foreach ($author_array as $author) :
$auth = get_userdata($author)->display_name;
$langCur = pll_default_language();
$auth_link = get_userdata($author)->user_login;
$homeurl = home_url();

echo "<li>";
echo "<a href='".$homeurl."/author/".$auth_link."/?cat=".get_cat_ID( $current_category )."' title=''>";
echo get_avatar( $author, $size = '140' );
echo "<span>";
echo $auth;
echo "</span>";
echo "</a></li>";
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```